# Change property of CheckBox in RowCreated in GridView

Tags: c#, asp.net, c#-4.0, gridview

I have a gridview that contains a CheckBox.

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" OnRowCreated="GridView1_RowCreated"
    BackColor="#F1EFC5" CssClass="SearchEveryWhere_Table" Width="500px">
    <HeaderStyle BackColor="#5391DD" ForeColor="White" />
    <Columns>
      <asp:BoundField DataField="CityCode" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" ItemStyle-VerticalAlign="Middle" Visible="false">
            <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" VerticalAlign="Middle" CssClass="EntryCell hideElement" />
      </asp:BoundField>
      <asp:BoundField DataField="Switch" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" ItemStyle-VerticalAlign="Middle"  Visible="false">
      <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" VerticalAlign="Middle" CssClass="EntryCell hideElement" />
      </asp:BoundField>
      <asp:BoundField DataField="Page_Number" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" ItemStyle-VerticalAlign="Middle"  HeaderText="Page">
           <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" VerticalAlign="Middle" CssClass="EntryCell" />
      </asp:BoundField>
      <asp:BoundField DataField="Name" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" ItemStyle-VerticalAlign="Middle"  HeaderText="Title">
            <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" VerticalAlign="Middle" CssClass="EntryCell" />
      </asp:BoundField>
      <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Access">
          <ItemTemplate>
               <asp:CheckBox runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" OnCheckedChanged="chkStatus_OnCheckedChanged" Checked='<%# Convert.ToBoolean(Eval("Access")) %>' ID="chkStatus" ClientIDMode="Static" />
           </ItemTemplate>
           <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" />
           <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" />
       </asp:TemplateField>
   </Columns>
 </asp:GridView>
```

I want change ID of this CheckBox to a value such this:

```
protected void GridView1_RowCreated(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {
            sp_GetPageAccess08_New_Result CurrentREcord = (sp_GetPageAccess08_New_Result)e.Row.DataItem;
            e.Row.Cells[4].FindControl("chkStatus").ID = "chkStatus_" + CurrentREcord.CityCode + "_" + CurrentREcord.Page_Number + "_" + CurrentREcord.Switch.ToString();
            if (CurrentREcord.Access == false)
            {
                e.Row.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb(252, 212, 243);
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {

    }
}
```

the problem is when I want to get `ID` I get `chkStatus` in `chkStatus_OnCheckedChanged`:

```
rotected void chkStatus_OnCheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        CheckBox chk = sender as CheckBox;
        string ID = chk.ID;
```

How I can Change `ID` of `chkStatus`? If it's impossible in how I can save that string in a property that can get in `chkStatus_OnCheckedChanged`?

thanks

Comment: I would not touch the ID attribute as this is required (and rebuilt on postback) Instead i would use the attributes of a checkbox.. Check out this link for using attibutes. http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/88324/Passing-command-arguments-to-a-checkbox

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Correction of my code

in your OnRowDatabound add

```
((CheckBox)e.Row.Cells[4].FindControl("chkStatus")).Attributes.Add("MyData", string.Format("{0}_{1}_{2}", CurrentREcord.CityCode, CurrentREcord.Page_Number, CurrentREcord.Switch.ToString());
```

in your checkbox check/uncheck event use this to get the data

```
string data = chkStatus.Attributes["myData"];
```

Comment: and How I can get `HiddenField` value in `chkStatus_OnCheckedChanged1`? thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can store the value in a custom attribute with the checkBox.Attributes.Add method, and you can also insert a HiddenField control near the CheckBox and store the value you want in its Value property (better).